# 2D animation of bitmaps in objective-c on iOS - How do I get best performance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, 2d

I have a few moving bitmaps on the screen and the animation is not smooth. I am using UIImageViews and animateWithDuration. 
What can I do to increase the performance? are there any guidelines that I should follow? Do I need a different approach, like use CGLayer or openGL? if so, can you point me to some starting article/tutorial?

thanks,
Nimrod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using `CALayer` for this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514

If that still is not enough, you may want to use cocos2d. It may seem like overkill, but it is rather easy to do 2D animation with it:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org